# Why resultset can't be put into session in php

Tags: php, session

I script it as follows,

```
session_start();
$employees = null;

if (isset($_SESSION['employees'])) {
    $employees= $_SESSION['employees'];

} else {

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "test", "emp_db");
$employees = $con->query("SELECT * from employee");
$_SESSION['employees'] = $employees;
}

echo "<table>";

foreach ($employees as $row) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo "<td>" . $row['emp_id'] . " </td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['emp_name'] . " </td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['emp_address'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

The first page access goes well, i.e. accessing from db.
But when I try to fetch from $_SESSION in 2nd page request, it says ...

```
"Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dbtemp.php on line 22". My line 22 is: foreach( $employees as $row) {
```

Any idea?

If resultset returned by php is connected resource (like Java), why we can still iterate it after closing the connection with DB?

When I call `get_resource_type($employees)` ... it says, its an object, not a resource. Then why an object is not being stored in session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace:

```
$_SESSION['employees'] = $employees;
```

With:

```
$_SESSION['employees'] = $employees->fetch_all();
```

Result set is not shared for scripts, which called with different time. In other words, you cannot properly save active `mysqli_result` in `$_SESSION` and use it after database connection was closed. However you can save `array`. [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) is what you needed.

Still, I don't think it's a good way. I recommend you to oversee your script.

Comment: **@STT LCU**, I just claimed space. :) Fixed.

Comment: Works well by passing MYSQLI_ASSOC in fetch_all(), defualt is MYSQLI_NUM

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from SO question [Storing database connection in a session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078843/storing-database-connection-in-a-session-variable/6078862#6078862)

You can't store database connections or result sets in the session, since those are resources, and:

> Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It
>   includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e.
>   objects which passes a reference to itself to another object).
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

You can extract a result set into a normal array and store that in the session like any other variable. That would be a fairly typical use case for sessions anyway. Just be careful not to store too much data in the session, as that can become more taxing than fetching it from the database.