# Including the same file over many pages

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a simple app for a school project that is not too big. I have the following files:
`signup.php`

`login.php`

`view_photos.php`

that have the following in common: they connect to a database and execute queries.  In every file I find myself repeating the your typical database connection code snippet:

```
$mysql = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'imagebox');

    if( $mysql->connect_errno ) {

        echo "Connection failure: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        exit();
    }
```

Is there a way to do this once in the `index.php` file and pass the connection to other pages without having to repeat the same line in every page that requires a database connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's `include` feature, though I recommend using `require` instead (as `require` aborts script execution if the file doesn't exist).

Documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Use `require_once` to prevent duplicate inclusion if you have cycles in your include-dependency tree.

Comment: Only thing that came to mind was storing the connection in a session variable so that it would be available across multiple pages withoug having to include the same code across many pages. As the saying goes, "write once use everywhere"

Comment: @RobertRocha Do not store database connections in session state: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078843/storing-database-connection-in-a-session-variable

Answer (score 0):

Place your common code in a separate file.  Then use

```
include('myfile.php');
```

where you want the common code to appear