# Saving the MySQL variable in a PHP $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

I create a MySQL connection object using mysqli_connect. The object works to access the database (e.g. mysqli_query). Using print_r I can see that it contains information I passed as parameters to mysqli_connect (e.g. host_info). However, when I save it in a $_SESSION variable, and then retrieve it later, it is mostly blank, and contains none of the data I initialized it with. I use pretty much the same method with FileMaker which also returns an object with the first command, and have no problem retrieving and re-using the object.

My workaround is to simply keep calling mysqli_connect to generate a new object (which works just fine), but that doesn't seem ideal.

Is there something special about this object that makes it impossible to be saved in a $_SESSION variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing database connection in a session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078843/storing-database-connection-in-a-session-variable)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to make a config file for connection to database and use it on everywhere you need to that connection, store it in a SESSION using your memory and some time maybe Session become destroy and your application become crash.
but is you want to store an object or array in a Session you must use [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). See the below example:

```
$_SESSION['connection'] = serialize($connection);

$connection= unserialize($_SESSION['connection']);
```

When want to store it in a session use serialize function, and when want to use it first unserialize then use it