# PDO execute different result than phpmyadmin

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

result done by php with var_dump: 29

result done by phpmyadmin: 3

i do this in phpmyadmin:

> SELECT * FROM tmp_foire_aux_vins_2012 WHERE 1 and prix_foire < 5 ORDER
>   BY enseigne ASC , prix_foire DESC

Why the return result is different than reality, the good result is 3

Here the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tmp_foire_aux_vins_2012 WHERE 1 $whereClause ORDER BY enseigne ASC $order";
$aRecordsListResultTab = $_SESSION["PDO"]->query($query, $param)->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $countResult = count($aRecordsListResultTab);
```

> var_dump $param
>       array
>         0 => int 5

---

> var_dump $whereClause
>       string ' and prix_foire < ?' (length=19)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tmp_foire_aux_vins_2012 WHERE 1 and prix_foire < ? ORDER BY enseigne ASC , prix_foire DESC "
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't pass mysqli connection in session in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125403/cant-pass-mysqli-connection-in-session-in-php)

Comment: @Neal, this is not a duplicate, i do it every days on all my website, this is just in this case with a prepared query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, in the DB, the type of the field was wrong...i change it to 'decimal', and it works like a charm